# Passing --tag-build or --tag-date to setuptools PEP 517 builder

Tags: python, versioning, setuptools, python-packaging, pep517

I am trying to create a snapshot/daily build of my Python package, using Setuptools and Build (the PEP 517 build module).

I have tried adapting this section of the Setuptools documentation: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/distribution.html#tagging-and-daily-build-or-snapshot-releases

However, none of the following commands worked:

```
python -m build --config-setting=--tag-date myproject
python -m build --config-setting=tag-date myproject
python -m build --tag-date myproject
```

The first two build the package without the version tag, while the third is an error. The results are the same when I use `--tag-build` instead of `--tag-date`.

How can I tell Setuptools to add the version tag, if none of the above options work?

**I do not have a `setup.py`, only a `setup.cfg`.** I cannot use `setup.py bdist_wheel --tag-date`, this command will say "File not found" because `setup.py` does not exist in my project.

**EDIT** after searching through Setuptools issue tracker, I also tried the following commands, with no success:

```
python -m build --config-setting=--global-options=--tag-date myproject
python -m build --config-setting=--global-options=tag-date myproject
python -m build --config-setting=global-options=--tag-date myproject
python -m build --config-setting=global-options=tag-date myproject
```

Answer (score 6):

Digging through the `setuptools` code, it looks like the `--tag-date` and the `--tag-build` options are available if passed to `egg_info`.

Example:

```
python setup.py egg_info --tag-date --tag-build=dev bdist_wheel
```

As for combining `setuptools` with `build`, you were almost there, it's just that you had to chain `egg_info` and `--tag-date` together:

```
python -m build -C--global-option=egg_info -C--global-option=--tag-date --wheel
```

Note that `--tag-date` doesn't take any value, it will just add date stamp (e.g. 20050528) to version number

Resources:

- https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#python--m-build---config-setting
- https://github.com/pypa/build/issues/446

Source code for setuptools: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/00fbad0f93ffdba0a4d5c3f2012fd7c3de9af04d/setuptools/command/egg_info.py#L159

Package version:

```
build            0.7.0
setuptools       60.10.0
```

Comment: Works, thanks, but unfortunately, it puts it in the wrong place!!! it overwrites the last part of the version number
i.e. 4.1.0 -> 4.1.<build tag> instead of the proper wheel format:
4.1.0-<build tag> (https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/#file-name-convention)

Comment: @Marc that has something to do with Python `packaging` requirements for version. See https://github.com/pypa/packaging/blob/main/src/packaging/version.py for information on how it looks for appropriate version names. (Not saying you aren't right that this is confusing and unhelpful...)

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m build -C--global-option=bdist_wheel -C--global-option=--build-number=<build-number>
```

Adds the [pep427](https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/#file-name-convention) approved build number after your version number. (`<version>-<build-number>`)

I haven't tried it with a string tag.